# How to add specific values to a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I want to do a simple plot between x and y where my x is `x = np.arange(0,100)`. My "y" values are mainly 0 but at some places it has a value of 0.5 and 1. Right now I have to write the whole values of y in a list as `y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5,0,0,......,1.....0]`. Is there a way where I can just write `y = np.arange(0,100)` to maintain the dimensionality of x and y and then input the specific values of y at the correct place? For example, at 8th position the y value is 0.5. So I want to write `y = np.arange(0,100)` and then input 0.5 at the 8th position of "y". Otherwise I have to manually write the whole y list. Thank for the help in advance.

Comment: NumPy arrays and standard Python lists support assignment to indices: `y[7] = 0.5`

Comment: Use `y = np.zeroslike(x)` and then assign with a list of indices; `y[list_of_indices_where_y_is_0,5] = 0.5` and the same for other values.

Comment: You can add values to a list by appending, inserting or indexed assignment. The Python list has built-in functions for these features namely *append()* and *insert()*. For direct assignment just use a positional index - e.g., *x[50] = 0.5*

Answer (score 0):

You could just use
`y = np.zeroes(100)`
and then change the specific values just like you would do with lists by 
`y[position where you would like to change] = 0.5`